# First statement did not work on dictionary result

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method that returns a dictionary as:

```
 public async Task<Dictionary<DateTime, double>> GetAvailableTimeOffWithExpiration(int userId)
        {
            ..../ code here

            Dictionary<DateTime, double> expirationDates = ...
            return expirationDates;
        }
```

Then I want to assign the first value of the dictionary to my DateTime variable of `TimeOffApproved` model as:

```
  var timeOffWithExpiration = await this.GetAvailableTimeOffWithExpiration(u.Id);
  var TimeOff = new TimeOffApproved()
                {
                    ExpirationDate = timeOffWithExpiration.First()
                };
```

But it is returning error:

> Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.DateTime, double>' to
> 'System.DateTime'

Why is trying to assign the dictionary if I'm using the `First()` statement?

Comment: If you call First on a Dictionary, you get back a key value pair that is the first entry of the dictionary. You can then access the Key or Value properties of that object. Looks like you want the key in this case. The error message is telling you the object you got isn't the same as you're trying to assign it to. That's the clue that you need to dig further into the result to get the actual value you want.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you intend to do with the data? A dictionary is probably not the right datastructure for you. You might want to use a tuple or a list of tuples instead.

Comment: Let me add that a dictionary (and its keys) is not sorted in any particular way.

Comment: @Fildor there is always to option of a SortedDictionary though, but you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `First()` method returns the first element of a collection in case of the `Dictionary` that is a KeyPair Value. To get date part you need to add `.Value` or `.Key` (depending on the part you need - in your case .Key) to the statement like this:

```
var timeOffWithExpiration = await this.GetAvailableTimeOffWithExpiration(u.Id);
var TimeOff = new TimeOffApproved()
{
   ExpirationDate = timeOffWithExpiration.First().Key
};
```

I would recommend a check to ensure that the first element is not null, like this for example (correction due to compiler error):

```
var timeOffWithExpiration = await this.GetAvailableTimeOffWithExpiration(u.Id);
if (timeOffWithExpiration != null)
{
   var TimeOff = new TimeOffApproved()
   {
      ExpirationDate = timeOffWithExpiration.Any() ? timeOffWithExpiration.First().Key : new DateTime()
   };
}
```

Comment: I did that,  but now it is trying to get the double value , it is throwing:  Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'System.DateTime'

Comment: Use `Key` instead of `Value`.

Comment: @Jesus sorry overlooked your Dictionary definition - please use .Key instead of .Value

Comment: @mason Thanks, forgot that == doesn't work with Dictionaries, I fixed the code, should compile now and be null safe